# Prove continuity using open sets

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $Y \subset R^m \rightarrow R^m $. We've got $f: Y \rightarrow R^m$ and $f$ is defined with rule $f(x) = x$. Prove that the function is continuos. I need to prove it using open sets. I don't really know how to use the definition in an example and I didn't find any good example on the internet. How should I prove it?

Edit: It's $R^m \rightarrow R^m$.

Comment: the prescription of $f$ can only be correct if $m=n$.

Comment: @drhab $f$ is Canonical function. I don't know the definition in English.

Comment: If e.g. $m=1$, $Y=\mathbb R^m=\mathbb R$ and $n=2$ then how is $f(1)$ defined? As $(1,0)$ maybe? That is not consistent with $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @drhab Got it. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ is open and $Y$ is equipped with the subspace topology then $f^{-1}(A)=Y\cap A$ is an open set in $Y$.

So preimages of open sets w.r.t. $f$ are open, or equivalently: $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Why is $f^{-1}(A)=Y\cap A$ an open set? $A$ is a closed set, so the intersection of an open and a closed set is again open set?

Comment: What I am saying is: if $A$ is open in $\mathbb R$ then $Y\cap A$ is open in $Y$ (equipped with subspace topology). Do you agree with that? I repaired a typo.

Comment: Sorry. I meant that $Y$ should be a closed set? Or not?

Comment: If $A$ is open in $\mathbb R$ then $Y\cap A$ is open in $Y$ (provided that $Y$ is equipped with subspace topology). The question whether $Y$ is closed, open, or something else is completely irrelevant in this matter. Note that I am not saying that $Y\cap A$ is open in $\mathbb R$, but that I am saying that $Y\cap A$ **is open in $Y$**.